# Editting succes.phtml

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I am adding conversion tracking code?

I have made a change to /staging1/.../checkout/success.phtml

Is the staging1 file the live one?

When I do a search using cpanel filemanager I only find one instance of success.phtml?

Assuming this is the correct file. Should the change be reflected on the server immediately or do I then have to flush the cache or something in the backend.

Cheers Colin

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what file is being served by logging into the admin of your site and seeing what theme is defined there (found in `system->config->general->design->theme`). Take note of the package too if a value is set there.

Once you know that, you know where the file needs to end up for you to safely edit it. What i mean by that is your theme might not have this template in it already. There is a place for all the basic front end files for the whole site, and your theme only needs to have the files that require changes in them, the rest of the file follow a fall back system and live in the `base` folder. This means that there is a chance the `success.phtml` is not in your theme, yet.

If it is in your theme, you will have a path that looks like this:

> app/design/frontend/{{your_package}}/{{your_theme}}/templates/checkout/success.phtml

If it's not in your theme, you will have a path that looks like this:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/templates/checkout/success.phtml

To correctly change this file, copy it from the base folder over to the theme folder. If you don't do this, you are technically doing a core edit. This means that your changes will get deleted when you do any upgrades to the site.

Once the file is over to your theme, make whatever changes you need. You don't have to clear cache, but i find for all my changes i do that anyway just as a sanity check.

A quick note: it would seem that you are editing files on a live site (since you are talking about cpanel as your method of editing files). If this is the case, be very careful. Magento can be tricky at times, and there are many things you can do to crash a live site. You are always better off testing changes in a dev env and then pushing those changes live.